# jQuery and Master Page makes an error when use button click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have one modal popup extender on my ASP.NET form.
But I have 3 different buttons that need to run same Modal.
So I'm trying to use jQuery to solve this problam. I have created a button (will be hidden in the future), and the ajax modal point to that button.
Now when I'm pressing each button (of the other three), It calls javascript function that sends click() function to the button that points to the modal.
The problam is that the modal works for only one moment and dissapeer, while it suppost to stay static. (When I press the "hidden button" it works well).

** I placed `ClientIDMode="Static"` on Master Page so the ID is working fine..
Here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    function pressMe() {
        $('#hide_button').click();

    }
</script>
```

My ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<asp:Button ID="Button_bodyPart" runat="server" Text="add/edit" OnClientClick="pressMe();" />

 <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
    BehaviorID="modalPopupExtender1"
    TargetControlID="hide_button"
    PopupControlID="popUpPanel"
    OkControlID="btnOk"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
 <asp:Button ID="hide_button" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:Panel ID="popUpPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">

    <h1> bla bla bla</h1>
    <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Thanks a-lot.

Comment: I don't seem to have a ModalPopupExtender on my plain-vanilla ASP.NET project. Are you referring to this project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34996/ASP-NET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-ModalPopupExtender-Co?

Comment: Thanks, but I found out what it was about. Apparently I needed to add the "return false" statment right after the pressMe(); call function so it wont turn to the server and ask for new page again.